# Receiving and sending, a TcpListener story

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am attempting to setup a tcp connection that will receive some data in an xml format from an outside user, parse it into a data table, do some heavy operations on the data table, and then turn around and send out an xml reply based on the alterations.

On the outside appearance it seems to be working just great, but then testing comes in and some major issues have been discovered. If multiple items come in at once, sometimes the wrong data is returned (like the third in is sent the fourth ins data reply) and there is a possibility that all data is not received properly on extremely long xml inputs.

#### The Receiving End

This code is being used to receive incoming transmissions, parse them into an xml document and then send them on their way to the appropriate section for processing. There are some global declarations *(like `_TcpClient`)* that I didn't show the initializations for because I figured their data type etc might be obvious.

```
private void ReceivePortMessages()
{
    int requestCount = 0;
    _TcpListener.Start();
    Debug.Print(" >> Server Started");
    _TcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Debug.Print(" >> Accept connection from client");

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            requestCount = requestCount++;
            NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)_TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));

            XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
            xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", dataFromClient));
            XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
            string rootName = root.FirstChild.Name;

            // Sends the data to an appropriate parser operation.
            RouteInboundXML(rootName, dataFromClient);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: Remote client disconnected. " + ex.ToString());
            _TcpClient.Close();
            _TcpListener.Stop();
            ReceivePortMessages();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
            _TcpClient.Close();
            _TcpListener.Stop();
            ReceivePortMessages();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

#### The Transmission Being Sent

After being received this data routes the xml document through a series of operations including insertion to the database, processing of data inserted into the database and then via an SQL service broker dependency, picks the data back up and converts it into an xml reply document. The dependency for the service broker then calls the `SendReply` method to return a reply to our users. That code can be found below:

```
private void SendReply(string reply)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream();
        string serverResponse = reply;
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
        Debug.Print(" >> " + serverResponse);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("SendReply: Remote client disconnected. " + ex.ToString());
        _TcpClient.Close();
        _TcpListener.Stop();
        ReceivePortMessages();
        return;
    }
}
```

Getting this figured out would be a great victory for me as I am fairly lacking in the network programming area *(as you maybe can tell)*. I have been working on this program for close to 5 months now and really only have this part left to unravel. Any coding suggestions, reading material, etc that help me round this out would be unbelievably appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the input stream on its own in Debug/Console, or used Breakpoints to follow your code?

Are you using tasks and BackgroundWorkers?

Comment: I have stepped through everything and when I go that route, everything has always came through correctly. It seems to follow the right path 90% of the time and I've never been able to catch it when it isn't. I am not using background workers, I can implement them if that could help. I am honestly just hoping I am messing up somewhere in the network code portion, considering this is all pieced together through various ambiguous google code snippets.

Comment: I would stick to your current build by not using the Background Workers for now, it is just a way for Out of Order Execution can take place.  I was trying to think of a probable cause.  I think, this is just an idea, the problem lies within how you are reading your Network Stream.  It may not be throwing an exception, but I don't think your code is waiting to receive all the data before executing.  My guess is, this has been a non-issue with small data because you are on a LAN and the network connectivity is high-speed / almost instant.  I think you need an "all data received?" checkpoint.

Comment: @RagingCain Okay, any chance you have an example of how I would hit that point? Link, code, etc? I'm not fully up on networking code. Never been my strong suit.

Comment: Sure thing, I will try and work your code in the answer below, give me a minute.

Comment: Added some tweaks you might try.

Answer (score 0):

Your byte buffer is static, I would switch it from:

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
```

to:

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

Also, I would switch to Unicode Encoding from:

```
string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
```

to:

```
string dataFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom);
```

Also add a read timeout before .Read(), start with 10 slightly increasing to see if any changes take effect:

```
networkStream.ReadTimeout = 10;
```